# ArcGIS, detect adjacent polygons with different values

Tags: arcobjects, adjacency

I am developing an ArcMap extension and I need to validate a particular case. I need to detect adjacents polygons that have one value equal, and the others not equal. I you take a look at the image, the yellow polygons are invalid and I need to inform the user. The sector is "Sector 2" on both polygons but, the next value is not the same (100 vs 200). If the sectors were different, the polygons would be valid. The violet and green polygons are okay, because for the violet one, the values are all the same and for the green one, the polygons are not touching.

The reason why I am doing this is because the user must use only one polygon for a same sector if the polygons are touching. So if all the values are the same, I can dissolve the polygons otherwise the dissolve won't work.

Is there a way to do this?

[image: Adjacent validation]

Comment: What sort of extension are you developing - ArcObjects or a Python AddIn?

Comment: ArcObjects, it can be multiple operations, I don't need it to be done with one tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with arcobjects.

Create a generic dictionary, `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` and load it using a cursor, looping through features from your polygon featureclass, such that the key is the ObjectID and a List of field values (e.g. "Sector 2", "100").

Find the `ITopologyExtension`, and get the [IMapTopology.Cache](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IMapTopology_Cache.htm).

Loop through each `ITopologyGraph.Edges` and check the dictionary to see if left and right parents have appropriate values.

If it's a violation, create an `ILineElement` with the edge's geometry, and add it to the `Map` using `IGraphicsContainer`.

Comment: Have to say that is a pretty nifty way of doing it! Simple question is `IMapTopology` an object that is limited by license level in anyway? Is it something that only Advanced licensed machines can use or can a Basic license level make use of this object?

Comment: IMapTopology is what the Topology Toolbar uses behind the scenes.  Since it works with Basic (ArcView) license, I suppose arcobjects code that uses it would also work.  Creating _Database_ topologies, OTOH, require Standard+ licensing.  I've never tested code with just a Basic license though.  http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0703/files/av_topo_tut.pdf

Comment: This sort of thing sure was simpler with workstation ARC/INFO.

Comment: I never used these interfaces before but, from what I see in Arcobjects help, calling the Edges.next method until it returns nothing will give me the adjacents features? So, if I have no adjacent features, Edges.next will always return nothing isn't?

Comment: If you populate your MapTopology with a featureclass that has at least one polygon feature, it should have at least one edge in the enumerator.

Comment: Ok, I found an example so I will try it. I should be ok, thanks!

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I am programming this and there is something that I don't get. I am getting the ITopologyEdge from TopologyGraph.Edges. Then I can get the parents, but the ITopologyEdge itself doesn't have a FID. I can only get the FID from the parents, so I can't compare my original polygon to the parents. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Math you need to loop through ITopologyEdge.Parents.  Keep in mind an edge can have more than one left or right parent.  For example, say you have a topology consisting of two featureclasses - country and state.  The national boundary along an ocean would have two left parents (a nation feature and a state feature) and no right parents (or vice versa).  A boundary between two states within the interior of the country would have two left parents and two right parents. On both sides you should find the same FID for the country, but different FIDs for the state, IIRC.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I had not noticed ITopologyEdge.Parents. I tried it and it seems to be working fine. Thanks a lot!